# error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.3 ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, libraries

I'm trying to run a binary file but I get:

```
./binary: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I already tried resolving it by installing *libssl-dev* as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811889/cannot-find-libcrypto-in-ubuntu), or installing *openssl* (my version is 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020) as said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74342708/how-to-fix-an-error-libcrypto-so-3-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-fil).

Both solutions didn't work. Which other solutions I could try to fix it?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: It sounds like `binary` was not built for Ubuntu 20.04 (which uses `libcrypto.so.1.1`). Where did you get it, and how did you install it?

Comment: A Google search brings me to this web page. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71337612/cannot-link-executable-node-library-libcrypto-so-3-not-found It says in a nut shell that the module may not be supported in ANY version.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! `binary` is actually a file for an university assignment. I wanted to solve the issues rather than asking the professor :/

Comment: Well, Ubuntu 22.04 provides libcrypto.so.3 (via package libssl3) so perhaps that is what you should be using?

Comment: Got it, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a few more options for you:

1. Check if the library exist with `find / -name libcrypto.so.3` if it exist apply this `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` ( with the good path )
2. Install the libssl3 package `sudo apt-get install libssl3-dev`
3. If that still dont work you can also simply trying reinstalling the library

Comment: Thanks for your help!
Unfortunately, for _1_ I got no result, for _2_ I get `Unable to locate`

Comment: try sudo add-apt-repository main then do the command again

Comment: Nope, same thing

Comment: What about apt-cache search libssl3-dev ?

Comment: Doesn't work, at this point I'm going to use Ubuntu 22 in VM as suggested above. Although thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing OpenSSL libraries by myself.

It uses GNU Autotools.

1. Download a release from https://github.com/openssl/openssl.
2. Read https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/NOTES-UNIX.md, and do `Configure`.
3. Then lovely `make`, then `make install`.
4. Do not forget to update your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, also you can add `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:path/to/openssl/installation` to `.bashrc`.